# NCEP reanalysis latitude and longitude represent center of cell?

Tags: meteorology, climate, reanalysis

I can't find any information regarding the lat and long in the NCEP Reanalysis. Do they represent the center of the cell?

Comment: Without knowing the answer, I'd check the coordinate values around the poles to figure this out.

Comment: @Christoph i have checked and they start at 88.542, 86.65 for gaussian variables and for the others they start at 90, 87.5. So I guess at least for gaussian it should be the center of the cell.